# Proving that a function is strictly monotonic

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$ be a function defined on the interval $[a,b]$ , $a,b>0$ such that: $g(x)=f(x)-kx^3$, $k>0$

--Knowing that the function $f$ defined as $|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^3-y^3|,k>0$ is continuous prove that g is strictly monotonic on $[a,b]$

**ATTEMPT** :

I let $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ such that $x_1<x_2$ and I have to either prove that $g(x_1)<g(x_2)$ or

$g(x_1)>g(x_2)$. So: $g(x_1)=f(x_1)-kx_1^3$ and $g(x_2)=f(x_2)-kx_2^3$ and now taking the

difference of the two I got: $g(x_2)-g(x_1)=f(x_2)-f(x_1)-k(x_2^3-x_1^3)$ and since

$x_2^3>x_1^3$ then $-k(x_2^3-x_1^3)<0$ . Where I'm stuck at is determining the sign of $f(x_2)-f(x_1)$. I know that $f$ is defined to be of Lipschitz, but I don't know how that's going to help me. Thank you for any help before hand.

Comment: What is f? This is certainly false for arbitrary continuous functions.

Comment: Take $f(x) = kx^3$ for a counterexample.

Comment: @AlexBecker f is defined as: $|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^3-y^3| , k>0$

Comment: @Module You should include that in the question.

Comment: Note that the condition give implies that $f$ is (Lipschitz) continuous.

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^3-y^3|$ is not a *definition*, as there are infinitely many functions that satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $x^3-y^3 = (x-y) (x^2+xy+y^2)$.

Then for $x \neq y$,  $|{f(x)-f(y) \over x-y } | < k (x^2+xy+y^2) $.

Now we have $g(x)-g(y) = f(x)-f(y) -k(x^3-y^3) = (x-y) ({f(x)-f(y) \over x-y } - k  (x^2+xy+y^2)) $.

Since $({f(x)-f(y) \over x-y } - k  (x^2+xy+y^2)) < 0$, we see that $g$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: So instead of supposing that x>y or y>x, I just suppose for x different of y and go on from there?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing to show for $x=y$ (as you must have $g(x)=g(y)$ in this case), so you might as well assume $x \neq y$.

Comment: But when you got to $({f(x)-f(y) \over x-y } - k  (x^2+xy+y^2)) < 0$ that will tell us that g is strictly decreasing only if x>y because $(x-y)({f(x)-f(y) \over x-y } - k  (x^2+xy+y^2)) < 0$ and vice versa for y>x we'll have g is strictly increasing right?

Comment: To show $g$ is strictly decreasing, we need to show that if $x>y$, then $g(x) < g(y)$. from above, if $x>y$, then $(x-y)>0$, and then $g(x)-g(y) < 0$. Hence $g$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: yes and if $x<y$ then we have the opposite ( $g$ is strictly increasing).

Comment: @Module: I don't know what you are trying to say. All you need to do is to show that if $x>y$, then $g(x)<g(y)$. That's it. That's what the above shows.

Comment: If $x<y$, then the above shows that $g(x)>g(y)$ which is still monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Oh yes yes I didn't pay attention to the other half which contains $f(x)-f(y)...$ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that 
$$|a-b|\ge|b|-|a|$$

Let $x<y$ then 
$$|g(y)-g(x)|=|f(y)-f(x)-(ky^3-kx^3)|\ge k|y^3-x^3|-|f(y)-f(x)|>0$$
hence we have $g(y)>g(x)$ or $g(x)>g(y)$

Now let $$A=\{(x,y)\in [a,b]\times[a,b]\;|\; x<y\}$$
then $A$ is a connex of $\mathbb R^2$ and let the function $$h\colon A\rightarrow \mathbb R,\; (x,y)\mapsto \frac{g(y)-g(x)}{y-x}$$
then $h$ is continuous and then $g(A)$ is a connex of $\mathbb R$ hence an interval (doesn't contain $0$) hence $g$ is strictly monotone on $[a,b]$.

Comment: So then I can conclude that if $g(y)>g(x)$ then g is strictly monotonic increasing and if $g(x)>g(y)$ then g is strictly monotonic decreasing right?

Comment: Yes but I think how we prove that if $g(y)>g(x)$ then this hold for **every** $x,y\in[a,b]$. The proof is incomplete.

Comment: now we have to suppose that y<x and do the same proof again right?

Comment: @Module I edited my answer and now it's complete.

Comment: You're welcome.